# Verify that method was called with an instance of superclass and then of child class

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class `Foo` and child class `Bar`. I want to verify that my service, which has a method `sendMessage(Foo foo)`, has sent a message of type `Foo` and then after that one of type `Bar`.

My first naive attempt was to do:

```
verify(communicatorMock, times(1)).sendMessage(any(Foo));
verify(communicatorMock, times(1)).sendMessage(any(Bar));
```

But this obviously returns a `TooManyActualInvocations` exception in Mockito. Since any object of type `Bar` is also an object of type `Foo`, this does work:

```
verify(communicatorMock, times(2)).sendMessage(any(Foo));
```

I haven't found a `ResultMatcher` that can distinguish between parent and child classes, or have I missed it? It there another way to check this without having to actually capture the arguments?

Comment: I think the better would be to expect `2 Foo` and `1 Bar` invocations.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that... Very clean and simple solution, thanks!!

Comment: It's better if we close this question.

Comment: @Mritunjay That might not be an ideal solution, because this kind of verification doesn't respect the order of invocations. OP states that `Foo` is send before `Bar`, but those verifications would also be true if `Bar` is send before `Foo`.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker but not both of them I think.

Comment: There's no need in my use-case to verify the order explicitly. I guess that you'd have to use an ArgumentCaptor if you would need to inspect order